# gcc and __attribute__((unused)) for auto references

Tags: c++, gcc, reference, auto

Using gcc (tested 5.4.0 and 6.1.1) with -Wall the following gives a warning about an unused variable for auto_ref, but not for the other variables. Clang does not issue any warnings. Is this difference for auto& variables intended, and why?

```
int main() {
    int __attribute__((unused)) int_var_unused = 42;
    int int_var = 42;
    int& __attribute__((unused)) int_ref = int_var;
    auto __attribute__((unused)) auto_var_unused = 42;
    auto auto_var = 42;
    auto& __attribute__((unused)) auto_ref = auto_var;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if it's a bug in GCC but it works like this

```
__attribute__((unused)) auto& auto_ref = auto_var;
```

and like this

```
auto& auto_ref __attribute__((unused)) = auto_var;
```

I guess the attribute is never intended to be placed between type declaration and the name. In the documentation I see the second version as example mostly.